# How to horizontally center draggable modal

Tags: css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a pop up window that is supposed to be `position:fixed` and draggable. The issue is that whenever the window pops up it uses a css transition so all of its properties are animated. I have tried to use `left:50%` `transformX:(-50%)` to horizontally center it but the pop up window jumps horizontally when it appears (as it animates the transform). I have also tried centering it with left:0 right:0 margin:0 auto; but the window also jumps out of position when you begin to drag. These issues are only present when the window first appears or it is dragged for the first time, after the first drag everything works as expected.

I pass in the following options to the draggable setter.

```
elem.draggable({ start: function() {

$(this).css({transform: "none", top: $(this).offset().top+"px", left:$(this).offset().left+"px"});

} });
```

This fiddle centers with `margin:0 auto`
[here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/alanz2223/4fp1evgg/)

this fiddle centers with `left:50% transform:translateX(-50%);`

[second fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alanz2223/s124yof1/)

Comment: An example including the relevant code, such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have added the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `margin: 0 auto` relies on the fact that the element's `left` and `right` properties are set to `0`. You are seeing the jump because jQuery UI manipulates the `left` positioning, and it is no longer `0` after dragging the element. The same applies to the `transformX:(-50%)` method. This will only center the element horizontally if `left` is set to `50%`.

The workaround is to set `left: 50%`, and then add `margin-left: -40px` to displace the element's width (i.e., a negative left margin based on half of the width of the element; in this case `-40px` since the element has a fixed width of `80px`).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nxs34yLz/)

```
.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: fixed;
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving the modal a width then using margin:0 auto; Typical in order to centre an element you need to give the element a width.

```
.centeredElement {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have added the fiddle.

Comment: when I change the position to relative, seems to work fine on first click, that's on the first fiddle example